# Quoting inside [[ ]] in bash shell

Tags: bash, quoting

Inside `[[ ]]` I do not need to quote variables right?

Rather than

```
if [[ "$flrm" == *"org"* || "$flrm" == "all" ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' "Delete: $fl"
fi
```

I can do

```
if [[ $flrm == *"org"* || $flrm == "all" ]]; then
  printf '%s\n' "Delete: $fl"
fi
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary). See in particular the section "Where you can omit the double quotes" of @Gilles' answer.

Comment: It says that within double brackets (which are shell special syntax) quoting is not required, except where a pattern or regular expression is expected on the right-hand side of `=`, `==`, `!=`, or `=~`.

Comment: This would mean that `[[` prevents word splitting of variable values, contrary to `[`'.

Comment: With single brackets `[ ]`, I have seen people using `if [ $var = "test" ]` and `if [ $var == "test" ]`.  I do not think there is a difference, or am I wrong?

Comment: @AdminBee All shells that support `[[ … ]]` support both `=` and `==`, so neither it more correct than the other. Ksh documents `=` as deprecated. Mksh documents `==` as deprecated. Bash and zsh recommend them equally (when inside double brackets). However, inside single brackets or after `test`, `=` is preferable because most shells that _don't_ support double brackets, and standalone `test` implementations, only recognize `=`.